# Mulitple Docker Containers on Port 80 with Same Domain

Tags: nginx, docker, digital-ocean

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822862/how-to-host-two-docker-containers-exposing-port-80-on-the-same-server) question but with only one domain.

Is it possible to run multiple docker containers on the same server, all of them on port 80, but with different URL paths?

For example:

Internally, all applications are hosted on the same docker server.

```
172.17.0.1:8080 => app1
172.17.0.2:8080 => app2
172.17.0.3:8080 => app3
```

Externally, users will access the applications with the following URLs:

```
www.mydomain.com                 (app1)
www.mydomain.com/app/app2        (app2)
www.mydomain.com/app/app3        (app3)
```

Comment: You can use nginx to set the routing to different applications. You can refer to this for example on how to do that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108044/nginx-routing-path-to-server

Comment: Several container **cannot** listen on the same port. More generally, a sole one process can bind to a socket (ip:port). Your need require a reverse proxy (such as nginx).

Comment: @Auzias They can, each has its own net namespace thus they are able to do exactly the same operations. They cannot, however, all be binded to the same port on the host machine, since the same port can be used only once. The solution here is to bind each container to other port on the host machine and use i.e nginx to do the routing based on the url

Answer (score 11):

I solved this issue with an nginx reverse proxy.

Here's the `Dockerfile` for the nginx container:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And this is the `nginx.conf`:

```
http {

        server {
              listen 80;

              location / {
                proxy_pass http://app1:5001/;
              }

              location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://app2:5000/api/;
              }
        }
}
```

I then stood up the nginx, app1, and app2 containers inside the same docker network.

Make sure to include the trailing `/` in the location and proxy paths, otherwise `nginx` will return a '502: Bad Gateway'.

All requests go through the docker host on port 80, which hands them off to the nginx container, which then forwards them onto the app containers based on the url path.